# Create Alias for Start->Run prompt

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

I am trying to create an alias to start a program through the *Start->Run* prompt. I have tried using the registry trick to force cmd.exe to autorun

```
doskey /macrofile=%UserProfile%\Desktop\doskey.txt
```

However this apparently does not apply to the Run prompt. I have looked through the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry entry and did not see anything that I though pertained to the run prompt.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you are trying to do but Win+R will bring up the run dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new shortcut on desktop and enter

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
```

as the location.

Now rt-clk -> Porperties on the shortcut, click on the `Shortcut Key` textbox and enter a shortcut key combo of your choice.
Mine is `Alt` + `Ctl` + `C`